# How to render React (with Redux) component only when props are received?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Let us assume we have a statefull React component (configured to work with Redux):

```
export class SomeComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    someObject: {}
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getNews();
    this.props.getFakeNews();
  }

  render() {
    const {
      news,
      fakeNews
    } = this.props;

    if(_.isEmpty(news) || _.isEmpty(fakeNews)){
      return <div>Loading</div>
    }else{
      return <div>Here all component stuff</div>
    }
}

SomeComponent.propTypes = {
  news: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  fakeNews: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export const Some = connect(
  state => ({
    news: newsSelectors.list(state),
    fakeNews: fakeNewsSelectors.list(state)
  }),
  {
    getNews,
    getFakeNEws
  }
)(withStyles(styles)(SomeComponent), withRouter(SomeComponent));
```

This component will re-render two times during getting news and fake news. In the render method we need to check if both of them are loaded.

Is there any way to trigger render only when all props are loaded?

In a perfect scenario I'd like to have no detailed null/empty check on the set of props. I believe React or Redux should perform this operation on its own as long the prop is configured as `required`.

Comment: You could do it in your middleware/ async layer. Only update `news` and `fakeNews` state (via an action) when both have returned. Depends on what you are using for your async calls (thunks, redux-observables etc.) as to how that would be impemented.

Comment: You definitely should check `thunk` or `saga`. With `redux thunk` you can use `mapDispatchToProps` which is exactly what you need.

Comment: Have you tried looking at reselect?

Comment: @Vivian No, I haven't tried yet. Is it necessary or at least helpful in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a lifecycle method `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState).

You can add the following method and it should resolve it for you:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) { 
  if (_.isEmpty(nextProps.news) || _.isEmpty(nextProps.fakeNews)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Partially it solves the problem. Now render is executed twice - at the beginning when state is empty and second time when empty check returns true. That's huge improvement! Although - it's not yet full solution of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
// HOC factory
function ifComponent (predicate, PlaceHolder) {
  return Component => class If extends React.Component {
    render () {
      if (predicate(this.props)) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />
      }
      return <PlaceHolder {...this.props} />
      }
    }
  }
}

// create the customHOC
const whenPropsLoaded = ifComponent(props => props.news && props.fakeNews, Loader);


// compose the two HOCs using the `compose` function in redux (simple function composition)
const News = compose(
  connect(getNewsProps),
  whenPropsLoaded(DisplayNews)
);
```

As a side note you may be interested in the `recompose` utility library bad its `branch` HOC ([docs here](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#branch)). I think this is pretty much what you want as you seem to know about HOCs.

Comment: That's nice and creative. But to be honest it's a bit overkill. In the essence it just moves null check from first lines of `render` method to predicate. What I try to find is more generic method of just executing render after all props are filled in. I'm really surprised it's not simple and provided by React or Redux framework...

Comment: You cannot escape testing for props presence each time they are passed to your component. Think about what doing it inside your component means for a "generic" solution. If generic means "paramaterizable" then your component needs to expose a place to make those checks (and to supply the appropriate predicate function). The thing is when using HOC (with redux for instance), might as well compose them for props->props manipulation, and compose Components for props->view manipulation.

Comment: As a side note, in the future "suspense" release, some sort of mechanism will be available for dealing with this kind of use case, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-6JC0_cOns for more details (still a work in progress). The guy presenting is the one who did the `recompose` thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid null and undefined values from redux. You can use Selectors it was very easy to avoid those things.

```
  const newsSelectors = (state) => {

     if(!state.list) { *//list is null or undefined*
       return [] or {} *//your wish (Proptypes required value)*
     }
     else {
       return state.list
    }
 }

export { newsSelectors };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the issue if you rewrite the render function as below.

```
render() {
    const {
      news,
      fakeNews
    } = this.props;

    return (
        {news && fakeNews ? 
            <div>Here all component stuff</div>
        :   <div>Loading</div> }
    )
}
```

I hope this helps you.